# Why might my db be locked on starting bitcoin-qt after a clean shutdown and reboot?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, wallet.dat, lightning-network-daemon, windows

I have LND v.16.2 running under Windows 10 with Bitcoin Core 23.0 on same machine.

When I need to reboot, I gracefully stop my LND node and close bitcoin-qt from the GUI, waiting until it has completely shut down. Then, when I try to restart bitcoin-qt after rebooting, it claims that the db is locked. Bitcoin-Qt is not running already, it is not in the autostart.

I have found that deleting the `wallet.dat` and creating a new one enables me to proceed. I am not worried about a financial loss, since the Bitcoin wallet contains no BTC, but it’s a yellow flag.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening and how I can prevent it?

.conf files below.

---

```
bitcoin.conf

server=1
listen=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=xxxxx
rpcpassword=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333 
txindex=1
```

---

```
lnd.conf

debuglevel=info
listen=0.0.0.0:9735
externalip=x.x.x.x   (my external fixed IP)
rpclisten=0.0.0.0:10009
restlisten=0.0.0.0:10010
tlsextraip=x.x.x.x    (my external fixed IP)
alias=nodenodealias
color=#ffdc00
maxpendingchannels=10
bitcoin.mainnet=1
bitcoin.active=1
bitcoin.node=bitcoind
bitcoind.rpcuser=xxxxxxx
bitcoind.rpcpass=yyyyyyyyyy
bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
```

The base directory for bitcoin is e:/bitcoin that contains the node's data, logs, configuration file, etc. That is reflected in the windows registry and lnd seems to find it with no problem.

```
bitcoind.dir=E:/bitcoin
```

LND files, on the other hand, are in Appdata/local/lnd.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft's [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) tool to see what files are open, and add the details to your question (You can limit the output to a specific folder or keyword such as 'bitcoin' by running the tool like this:

```shell
handle.exe E:\bitcoin
```

That will tell you all the files existing in `E:\bitcoin` that are open, and which process has them open.  That should allow you to narrow down what process is causing bitcoin-qt to report that error.

If `handle` shows no open files, then perhaps you have a permissions issue - i.e. maybe bitcoin-qt can't open the wallet.dat due to limited permissions.  Use `icacls.exe e:\bitcoin` to check permissions.