# How can I update lnd to 0.17 on Windows?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, windows, installation

I am running lnd 0.16.2 on a Windows 10 system.

I just downloaded v0.17. Can I just drop the new files
`lnd.exe` and `lncli.exe`
into my directory and run on the same install?  Any tweaks needed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply stop LND, replace lnd.exe and lncli.exe with the new files and start it again. As described in the release notes, there is a database migration that needs to run once after the update, so make sure not to stop LND before that finishes.

Comment: Thanks.  Since you seem in the know, can you look at my question here https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/119443/why-might-my-db-be-locked-on-starting-bitcoin-qt-after-a-clean-shutdown-and-rebo?noredirect=1#comment136334_119443                                     I have yet to get a satisfactory answer. Thx in advance.